# Public Transportation Pass for 3 days in Zurich (2 zones)

Tags: trains, buses, switzerland, zurich

I will spend 3 days in Zurich and I plan to use public transportation. In order to avoid buying a single ticket every time I prefer to buy a 3 days pass (or a single day pass) to facilitate my trip.

I need to go also (one time) to Wallisellen and according to [ZVV maps](http://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/zones/zone-maps.html) is on a different zone (121) than Zurich (110), the other movements will be inside Zurich area (110).

Which is the more convenient ticket for 3 days considering this 2 zone movement?
There is a price list in English or a fare calculator online? (the only thing I found is the zone map I linked above)

Comment: Are you arriving by plane or by train?

Comment: I will arrive by train

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tickets prices for public transportation in Zurich can be found here:
[Tickets - ZVV](http://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets.html).

Be aware that regarding fares, Zurich (110) as well as Winterthur (120) count as two zones.

For your travel arrangement, I would recommend to buy two day passes for zone 110 (1-2 zones fare) and one day pass for zones 110 & 121 (3 zones fare) for your trip to Wallisellen (121).

This should cost CHF 31.20 (2 x CHF 8.80 + 1 x CHF 13.60) according to the following price list:
[Day pass - ZVV](http://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets/daypass.html).
Prices assume you travel 2nd class.

You can buy those three day passes in advance, they will become valid upon stamping ('Tageswahlkarte'). I would recommend to buy the three day passes on arrival at either a ZVV or SBB ticket counter. You will find one at Zurich airport as well as at Zurich main station.

There are other options, which may be marginally cheaper, but they would require you to buy more tickets or they would limit how long you can travel in each zone. (You stated you would rather want to buy less tickets for convenience.)

Be aware that using public transportation during nighttime may lead to an additional surcharge of CHF 5. You can find more information on the night supplement here: [Night supplement - ZVV](http://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets/night-supplement.html).

Comment: thank you very much! a daily ticket basically is the same price as two single tickets so it's more convenient for me. Thank you also for the zone explanation. Regarding the night supplement looks like it is between 1AM and 5AM, I don't plan to travel during that hours but good to know.

Comment: Note that if you buy daily tickets for 110, you can also buy a zone extension ticket (i.e. add an additional zone such as 121) either for an hour or for a 24 hours.